Polars: Create a new column with an array of dates from two different date columns storing the start and end of the range
I have a dataframe with a date start and date end (Start Promotion and End Promotion). I would like to use Python Polars to create a new column (from the previously mentioned columns) that will be an array or struct object. The purpose in this is so that the column can be exploded creating a value for each date that can be joined to another data frame later.
This is an example data frame:



Start Promotion
End Promotion
Price




2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12


2023-12-30
2024-01-01
10



The desired end result is:



Start Promotion
End Promotion
Price
Promotion Dates




2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12
["2024-05-01", "2024-05-02", "2024-05-03", "2024-05-04", "2024-05-05"]


2023-12-30
2024-01-01
10
["2023-12-30", "2023-12-31", "2024-01-01"]



Here is an example of what it should look like if exploded:



Start Promotion
End Promotion
Price
Promotion Dates




2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12
"2024-05-01"


2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12
"2024-05-02"


2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12
"2024-05-03"


2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12
"2024-05-04"


2024-05-01
2024-05-05
12
"2024-05-05"


2023-12-30
2024-01-01
10
"2023-12-30"


2023-12-30
2024-01-01
10
"2023-12-31"


2023-12-30
2024-01-01
10
"2024-01-01"



Here is an example data frame to attempt it with:
import polars as pl

data = {
    "Start Promotion": ["2024-05-01", "2023-12-30"],
    "End Promotion": ["2024-05-05", "2024-01-01"],
    "Price": [12, 10]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

Let me know if you have any clarifying questions.

you can use .date_ranges() for that:
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.date_ranges("Start Promotion", "End Promotion").alias("Promotion Dates")
    )
)

┌─────────────────┬───────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Start Promotion ┆ End Promotion ┆ Price ┆ Promotion Dates                 │
│ ---             ┆ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---                             │
│ date            ┆ date          ┆ i64   ┆ list[date]                      │
╞═════════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2024-05-01      ┆ 2024-05-05    ┆ 12    ┆ [2024-05-01, 2024-05-02, … 202… │
│ 2023-12-30      ┆ 2024-01-01    ┆ 10    ┆ [2023-12-30, 2023-12-31, 2024-… │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

